# error_code":401 in channel chat id

Tags: telegram

I am trying to get my chat_id for my telegram channel. Bot I get this line error:

```
 {"ok":false,"error_code":401,"description":"[Error]: Unauthorized"}
```

I try with this:[How to obtain the chat_id of a private Telegram channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33858927/how-to-obtain-the-chat-id-of-a-private-telegram-channel)

My Channel Name is: MyName
My link is:https://telegram.me/MyNameIsChannel.

Answer (score 0):

1 @Botfather choose your bot.

2 /revoke

3 you will get a new token replace your former token that can sloved your isssue

4 https://api.telegram.org/botnewToken/getUpdates