# Method to find telegram private channel id no longer works?

Tags: python, telegram

Previously to find my private channel id I was:

Log into Telegram via web: https://web.telegram.org
Find your channel and copy the URL. You should have something like this: https://web.telegram.org/#/im?p=c**NUMBER***number
The numbers between "c" and "*" are the ID of your private channel.

Now tell your bot to send the messages to chat_id=-100NUMBER

Seems it no longer work, chat not found using this method

Can anyone confirm if something changed?

Answer (score 1):

This method still works, you need to use the first **NUMBER** between c and _ in the **https://web.telegram.org/#/im?p=cNUMBER_number** string. 
I you get some *chat_id not found* error whan you try to send the message, please make sure that your bot has been added to your channel as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is still good, and you can also use this method

- You should convert it to the public with some @channelName and Send the message to this channel through Bot API https://api.telegram.org/bot111:222/sendMessage?chat_id=@channelName&text=123
- As the response, you will get info with chat_id of your channel.{ "ok" : true, "result" : { "chat" : { "id" : -1001005582487, "title" : "Test Private Channel", "type" : "channel" }, "date" : 1448245538, "message_id" : 7, "text" : "123ds" } }
- Now you can convert Channel back to private (by deleting channel's link) and send message directly to this chat_id "-1001005582487" https://api.telegram.org/bot111:222/sendMessage?chat_id=-1001005582487&text=123

If you need more detailed explanation, [read this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33858927/how-to-obtain-the-chat-id-of-a-private-telegram-channel)

Answer (score 0):

Just forward a message of your private channel to a Telegram Bot, and refer to [`Message.forward_from_chat`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) object. If you need a quick solution, you may try to use a bot like [@JsonDumpBot](https://t.me/JsonDumpBot) or [@getidsbot](https://t.me/getidsbot).