# How can I send message to telegram using API and C#?

Tags: c#, telegram

I have channel and I want to send automatic messages to this channel using C# and telegram API.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a bot and add that as an administrator to your channel

help:

[Adding Bot as administrator to channel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33497769/2315116)

[Creating Bot](https://core.telegram.org/bots)

then use the following code to send message to your group

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + yourToken + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + channel_id + "&text=" + message);
req.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

var result = req.GetResponse();
req.Abort();
```

**yourToken** is your bot's token, **channel_id** is your channel's ID and **message** is a string that you want to send to your channel

Comment: WebRequest is in **System.net**

Comment: How can I find **Token**?