# Can a Telegram bot read messages of channel

Tags: python, web-scraping, telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-api

Can a telegram bot read/access a telegram channel that neither I or the bot is administrator of?

I know that up to last November it was not possible, but I have heard some people have done this, but so far I am not able to do it.

I would really appreciate your input and knowledge.

P.s. any workaround would be great.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The [FAQ](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#what-messages-will-my-bot-get) reads:

> 1. All bots, regardless of settings, will receive:
>
>    - All service messages.
>    - All messages from private chats with users.
>    - All messages from channels where they are a member.
> 2. Bot admins and bots with privacy mode disabled will receive all messages except messages sent by other bots.
> 3. Bots with privacy mode enabled will receive:
>
>    - Commands explicitly meant for them (e.g., /command@this_bot).
>    - General commands from users (e.g. /start) if the bot was the last bot to send a message to the group.
>    - Messages sent via this bot.
>    - Replies to any messages implicitly or explicitly meant for this bot.

So, if your bot is a member of the channel it will receive all messages except those sent by other bots.

Comment: Thanks lufte for quick response, but can you also tell me, how my bot can join PUBLIC channels? is there a way thru link of channel, username? thanks again

Comment: That's a different question. Maybe you can get some clues from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33126743/how-do-i-join-my-bot-to-the-channel.

Comment: It's not posible yet, you can only recieve updates of messages with bot, if you want to get past message you need the core API

Comment: Please, show us simple code snippet as well

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the other type of Telegram API: [Telegram [client] API and TDLib](https://core.telegram.org/#tdlib-build-your-own-telegram)?

Using [telethon library](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) makes it easy to read channels history (see [telethon docs](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/basic/installation.html)).

For this, we need an `api_id` and an `api_hash`.  So, do the following:

1. Log in to [Telegram core](https://my.telegram.org/)
2. Open the [API development tools area](https://my.telegram.org/apps)
3. Fill out the simple form there
4. Now you can receive your `api_id` and `api_hash`
   <sub>For more information, see Telegram's help documentation about [how to get your API credentials](https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id).</sub>

Here is an example code that gets the last *5* messages of *targetChannelId*:

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient


API_ID = 123456     # See above for how to get it
API_HASH = '123abc' # See above for how to get it
client = TelegramClient('my-client', API_ID, API_HASH)


async def main():
    async for message in client.iter_messages('targetChannelId', limit=5):
        print(message.id, message.text)


with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

The first time you run this code it asks your phone number or bot token. Enter your **phone number** in the format `+9912345...` where `99` is your country code and the rest is your phone number.
It then may send a login code to your Telegram app; enter it in the console.

**Note**: Only users (phone numbers) can see channel history messages; bots cannot (at least in telethon). Bots can only listen for channel **updates** only if they are one of its **administrators**.

The `client.iter_messages()` accepts other parameters like `min_id` which can be used to get messages only after a specific message (for example, we can save the last message id that we have processed and next time pass that id as `min_id` so only messages after that message are returned).