# PHP Telegram message routines

Tags: php, telegram

I'm trying to filter and resend a messages from Telegram News Channel(public) using PHP. I can set Webhook to listen own chats and channel by bot.
How I can set Webhook to listen specific channel. (I'm not admin of News Channel, so I can't to add my bot into it)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Get it's answer.
[Can a Telegram bot read messages of channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42672034/can-a-telegram-bot-read-messages-of-channel)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).