# Can a bot be an admin for a telegram channel?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I’m reading that there are some constraints with a bot being an admin for a telegram channel but I’m puzzled why. I’m also reading that there is a limit of channels that a an admin can be an admin of. Is this true?

I need a bot to be the admin of possibly hundreds of channels. Is that viable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible that a bot can be an admin in a public/private channel.

> I’m also reading that there is a limit of channels that an admin can be an admin of

It's not true. Every channel can have admin include human or bot.

You can see how to add a bot in a channel [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33126743/)

and then you can promote its permission.