# How to change Telegram Bot settings knowing only the token

Tags: telegram-bot

Someone set up Matterbridge to transfer the contents of a Telegram channel into a Mattermost channel. To do this, they created a Telegram bot.

Unfortunately, the person has disappeared (Covid?), and we don't have full details of the account used to set up the bot.

We do have the Bot Token (from the Matterbridge config file).

Is there any way we can find out more about the bot, change its settings, join it to other channels, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bot's token allows you to do *anything* the Bot API is capable of doing. You can check a list of available methods here https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#available-methods.

> "Is there any way we can find out more about the bot"

Some limited info, yes. Try calling `https://api.telegram.org/botBOT_TOKEN/getMe` and `/getWebhookInfo`.
You might be able to get a webhook url - in case it was set up to use one.

> "... change its settings"

Rather not. You'd need access to wherever the bot is hosted. It's not possible to tell exactly without knowing how the bot works. But anything specific found within the bot's processing script/program will not be accessible to you.

> "...join it to other channels"

Yes. As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33126743/how-do-i-add-my-bot-to-a-channel). Though it may not be useful to do. Depends on how the bot is set up to work.

Comment: Thanks. I now have the result of getMe, so I know the first_name, username and id. I guess the actual bot code is just Matterbridge, and I know where that is.